# handling unicode strings in Windows

Tags: python, unicode, window

For the first time, I was trying out one of my Python scripts, which deals with unicode characters, on Windows (Vista) and found that it's not working. The script works perfectly okay on Linux and OS X but no joy on Windows. Here is the little script that I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys, codecs

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
print "\nDefault encoding\t: %s" % sys.getdefaultencoding()
print "sys.stdout.encoding\t: %s\n" % sys.stdout.encoding

## Unicode strings
ln1 = u"?0>9<8~7|65\"4:3}2{1+_)(*&^%$£@!/`\\][=-"
ln2 = u"mnbvc xzasdfghjkl;'poiuyàtrewq€é#¢."

refStr = u"%s%s" % (ln2,ln1)
print "refSTR: ", refStr

for x in refStr:
    print "%s => %s" % (x, ord(u"%s" % x))
```

When I run the script from Windows CLI, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\san\Scripts>python uniCode.py

Default encoding        : utf-8
sys.stdout.encoding     : cp850

refSTR;  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uniCode.py", line 18, in <module>
    print "refSTR; ", refStr
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position
 30: character maps to <undefined>
```

I came across [this Python-wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) and tried a few things from there but that didn't work. Does anyone know what I'm still missing? Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: This is one thing where it might make sense to start with Python 3, which is rather clearer about unicode vs. bytes than Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows console has a Unicode API, but not utf-8. Python is trying to encode Unicode characters to your console's 8-bit code page cp850, which obviously won't work. There's supposedly a code page (`chcp 65001`) in the Windows console that supports utf-8, but it's severely broken. Read [issue 1602](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602) and look at `sys_write_stdout.patch` and `unicode2.py`, which use Unicode wide character functions such as `WriteConsoleOutputW` and `WriteConsoleW`. Unfortunately it's a low priority issue.

FYI, you can also use IDLE, or another GUI console (based on pythonw.exe), to run a script that outputs Unicode characters. For example:

```
C:\pythonXX\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw -r script.py
```

But it's not a general solution if you need to write CLI console tools.

Comment: Are you saying *Unicode* when you mean some Microsoft thing like UCS-2 or UTF16-BE?  Otherwise I can’t understand what you’re saying.

Answer (score 1):

The `setdefaultencoding` and `getdefaultencoding` denote the encoding followed by the python interpreter and while you use `sys.stdout.encoding`, it denotes the encoding used by your terminal.  You can verify this, if you were to write it in the file vs print in the terminal.

The way to 'fix' this program would be to set the terminal encoding to something that you want (utf-8) or write to the file and open the output in the editor which supports those particular characters.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question: How do I set the terminal encoding to utf-8? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: You can use Google.  You'd find this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490874.aspx

Comment: @S.Lott: I tried a few combinations in Google but nothing helped me so far. I haven't come across the link you sent but I don't see UTF-8 in there. The closest I see latin-1. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: More search that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+terminal+unicode